# Flutter - Subscript from json file

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a json file to store my data and I need to show some of it on the screen.

For example, when I make a simple text widget and use this string:

```
Text("a\u2081")
```

It shows "a" with a subscripted "1".

**The problem is that when I load it from a json file it just shows "a\u2081".**

This is how I load the data:

```
var myData = await rootBundle.loadString("data/my_data.json");
var data = await json.decode(myData.toString());
```

I'm storing the values in objects:

```
Text(TestReport[i].text) // where TestReport[i].text = "a\u2081"
```

Is there a way how to show the subscript?

Comment: how to save your JSON?, make sure before saving convert to string with  jsonEncode({'data':"a\u2081"}); then decode by jsonDecode("{'data':"a\u2081"}")

Comment: It looks like your JSON data isn't saving the Unicode value of "\u2081" but instead the literal unescaped string value of "\u2081" (i.e. `"\\u2081"`).

Comment: I added useful code in article https://medium.com/@anna_muzykina/superscript-and-subscript-text-in-flutter-2d4f76ef18d3